# gcloud deploy app inside cloudbuild with arbitrary name

Tags: deployment, gcloud, app.yaml

I have gcloud inside my cloudbuild.yaml how could I make the deployed name something that I want?
It looks it is like https://[Project Name].ey.r.appspot.com/ but I want to have it like https://MyNameappspot.com/

Should I do it inside app.yaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can help determine the URL that e.g. App Engine apps will use but there are constraints on how your apps' subdomain names are determined.

See App Engine [How Requests are Routed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/how-requests-are-routed) for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks but anyhow it does not let me to change it what I want except if I have my own domain

Comment: Yes, that's correct.